# rxjs don't emit until value is not null

Tags: rxjs

I have an Observable (let's call it myob$) which emits values like this:

```
----- null ----- 1 ----------- 5 ---->
```

If I do:

```
myob$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

the output is:

```
----- null ----- 1 ----------- 5 ---->
```

Can I add a pipe so it does not emit until the value from myob$ is not null?

Something like:

```
myob$.pipe(x => ignoreEverythingUntilXIsNotNull).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

So that the output is:

```
--------------- 1 ----------- 5 ---->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## RxJS v6 UPDATE

Using filter is still a great way to go but now have to use [Pipe](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pipe). Also added a cleaner check on the filter using [Falsy logic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

```
myob$.pipe(filter<YourObject>(Boolean)).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Answer (score 9):

bah I'm thick, I think you just need to do:

```
myob$.filter(x => !!x).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

assuming no 0's are being emitted :)